# Can I add an index on a view in mariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to create an index on a view in mariaDB. Is this possible?

Note that, I can't create an index on tables since admininstrator permissions are not given to access tables.

Comment: Create the index on the base table instead.

Comment: Well the problem is i have no access to the table. No permission to view the tables. I was given only a few particular views, which contain lots of data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot create indexes on a **View** in MariaDB.

Indeed, Views are not real relations, but simply aliases on relations (tables).

You could have created indexes on a **Materialized View** but MariaDB does not implement (in a native way) Materialized Views as of today.

Comment: The ticket for materialized views in Mariadb can be found here: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12163. It hasn't been updated since 2017.